# What is wrong with this RLE Algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I've done this RLE code a while back and I seem to be blind on what is going on wrong. The expected output of encode() should be 'a1b2c3' but instead I'm getting the value 'None'.

```
def encode(text):
if not text:
    return ""
else:
    last_char = text[0]
    max_index = len(text)
    i = 1
    while i < max_index and last_char == text[i]:
        i += 1
        return last_char + str(i) + encode(text[i:])

print(encode("abbccc"))

def decode(text):
if not text:
    return ""
else:
    char = text[0]
    quantity = text[1]
    return char * int(quantity) + decode(text[2:])

print(decode("a1b2c3"))
```

Regards

Comment: Well, the indentation is obviously wrong. That may be a problem.

Comment: Your `return` should be outside the loop

Comment: In Python indentation is not cosmetic - it is used to mark the beginning and end of a statement block.  Without proper indentation (=> the _exact_ indentation used in your real code), it's impossible to tell what's wrong with your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only the indentation.

```
def encode(text):
    if not text:
        return ""
    else:
        last_char = text[0]
        max_index = len(text)
        i = 1
        while i < max_index and last_char == text[i]:
            i += 1
        return last_char + str(i) + encode(text[i:])

print(encode("abbccc"))

def decode(text):
    if not text:
        return ""
    else:
        char = text[0]
        quantity = text[1]
    return char * int(quantity) + decode(text[2:])

print(decode("a1b2c3"))
```

output:

```
a1b2c3
abbccc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def encode(text):
last_char = text[0]
max_index = len(text)
i = 1
while i < max_index and last_char == text[i]:
    i += 1
return last_char + str(i) + encode(text[i:])

text = "abbccc"
print(encode(text))

def decode(text):
if not text:
    return ""
else:
    char = text[0]
    quantity = text[1]
    return char * int(quantity) + decode(text[2:])

text2 = "a1b2c3"
print(decode(text2))
```

Why is he getting an error:     last_char = text[0]
IndexError: string index out of range

if clearly first value within the array is 'a'.